# Updating a column based on a condition in another column in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let me start by admitting that this is probably not the best engineering, but I am having the following question/problem.

I want to add values to column 'gc_stand'. I have data which connects the 'gc_stand' to 'startnummer' (e.a. (5 , 145) (78 , 2) (125 , 98) etc).

So my question is how to update the 'gc_stand' column without having to enter the values manually (around 200 values), but based on the connection between `gc_stand` and `startnummer`. I have inserted the data for the first two columns (`startnummer` and `rit_uitslag`) the same way (insert instead of update).

I am thinking about something like:

```
update etappe_4
    set gc_stand = ??
where startnummer = 'startnummer'
```

But where should i input my connected values then?

I have inserted the values by:

```
INSERT INTO etappe_1 (startnummer, rit_uitslag)
    VALUES (1,5), (2,145), (3,32) etc etc
```

And now I want to add the column (gc_stand). It is not possible by inserting, because it would create new rows. So therefore i guess i have to use UPDATE. But how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make it easy to help you - take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I dont understand what do you think.
You need update value from STARTNUMMER to GC_STAND?

Comment: I am sorry, as you can see I am new to SO. So, no screenshot of my table is suppose. But i can not give you code, because i do not have code for this problem yet (it is kind of my question). I can try to explain the problem to you a bit further. I am working on a Tour de France pool. For that I am inserting the stage results, general classification standing etc. per stage (table for each stage). I have inserted the startnumber of each rider (unique) and their stage result, because I can retrieve them from the website. (Like I mentionded (startnumber 1 , pos. 36), (startnumer 87, pos. 2) etc.

Comment: And now I want to add the general classification standing the same way. Because again, i can retrieve that data from the website (startnumber 1, GC position 40), (startnumber 94, pos. 172) etc. So, i want to insert/update the GC position, depending on the startnumber. Is that clear enough? Otherwise, please tell me what more information you need!

Comment: You can create triggers on tables for insert or update operations check out this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to make out what you are after, but I *think* you are looking for something like this:

```
update etappe_4
    set gc_stand = etappe_1.rit_uitslag
from etappe_1 
  where etappe_1.startnummer = etappe_4.startnummer
```

Note that this will only work properly if `startnummer` is unique in both tables.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This will not be the solution, because this would give the gc_stand table the same values as the rit_uitslag (it is about cycling: the general classification will not be the same as the stage result, except for the first stage). But i have found a solution/workaround. I have made multiple underlying tables in which i can insert data instead of update it.

Comment: @Tom with the little information you provided this was the only answer possible. Next time please provide the complete definition of the tables involved (as `create table` statements) and proper and complete example data (ideally as `insert` statements). "Multiple underlying tables" sounds like a overly complicated way to solve a simple [UPDATE with a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+sql-update+join)